# No conversion from long unsigned int to long unsigned int&

Tags: c++, g++

I receive the error message *No known conversion for argument 2 from `long unsigned int` to `long unsigned int&`* when I try to compile the following code:

```
void build(int* &array, unsigned long& index) {
  if (index == 0)
    return;
  else {
    heapify(array, index);
    build(array, index-1);
  }
}
```

Can someone explain why this happens, and what the logic is behind this error?

Answer (score 6):

The second argument of `build` requires a reference (marked with `&`). A reference is kind of like a pointer, so you can only use an actual variable that has a memory address.

This is why you can't use an expression like `index-1`.

Answer (score 2):

A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue in C++. `index-1` returns a temporary, which, if bound to a reference would immediately go out of scope and you would have a dangling reference. A const reference *can* be bound to a temporary though, and it will prolong the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the const reference. So, if you can change `unsigned long&` to `const unsigned long&` it should work.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of `build` is a reference to `unsigned long`. But in the recursive call, you pass it an actual value (i.e. an "rvalue").

If you rewrite the function as follows, the problem should disappear.

```
void build(int* &array, unsigned long& index) {
   if (index == 0)
     return;
   else {
    heapify(array,index);
    index -= 1;
    build(array,index);
  }
}
```

But note that this might not be what you want. The value of `index` will be changed before the recursive call. You might want to change it back (`index += 1`) after the call, depending on what the overall purpose of the function is.

Answer (score 1):

See *The Design and Evolution of C++*, chapter 3.7, p86, which gives this example:

```
void incr(int& rr) { rr++; }

void g()
{
    double ss = 1;
    incr(ss)     // note: double passed, int expected
                 // (fixed: error in Release 2.0)
}
```

In the first version of C++ a temporary of type `int` was created from the `double`, with value `1`, then that temporary was passed to `incr` and `ss` was not modified.  To prevent this sort of unexpected behaviour the language was changed so that a temporary (i.e. an unnamed variable) cannot bind to a non-const reference, because a non-const reference parameter usually implies the parameter will be modified to pass information back to the caller. If a temporary is silently created the caller loses that information, e.g.

```
void* get_ptr(int& error);  // sets error=0 if returned pointer is valid

void g()
{
    unsigned err = 0;        // oops, wrong type
    void* p = get_ptr(err);  // uh-oh, error status stored in temporary
    if (err == 0)            // condition always true
        use_ptr(p);          // uh-oh! pointer may not be valid!
}
```

If a non-const reference is allowed to bind to a temporary then this program is dangerous, because `get_ptr(err)` will create a temporary `int`, like `get_ptr(int(err))`, and set the error status in the temporary, so `err` will still be zero even if there's a problem.

If the function author wants to be able to accept temporaries, because the argument won't be used to pass information back to the caller, then the function can take parameters by value:

```
void blah(int rr);
```

or by const-reference:

```
void blah(const int& rr);
```

Answer (score -1):

what line is your error message on? It seems like you are passing in a `long unsigned int` for index, when it needs a `long unsigned int` by reference (in other words the address of the `long unsigned int`)

Comment: it's on `build(array,index-1);`

Comment: then gustav's answer is what you were looking for